# Perl hash formatting

Tags: perl

I have a log file like below

```
ID: COM-1234
Program: Swimming
Name: John Doe
Description: Joined on July 1st
------------------------------ID: COM-2345
Program: Swimming
Name: Brock sen
Description: Joined on July 1st
------------------------------ID: COM-9876
Program: Swimming
Name: johny boy
Description: Joined on July 1st
------------------------------ID: COM-9090
Program: Running
Name: justin kim
Description: Good Record
------------------------------
```

and I want to group it based on the Program (Swimming , Running etc) and want a display like,

```
PROGRAM:  Swimming
==>ID  
    COM-1234
    COM-2345
    COM-9876

PROGRAM:  Running
==>ID   
    COM-9090
```

I'm very new to Perl and I wrote the below piece (incomplete).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "%%%%";
open( AFILE, "D:\\mine\\out.txt");
while (<AFILE>)
{
@temp = split(/-{20,}/, $_);
}
close (AFILE);

my %hash = @new;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

I have read from perl tutorials that hash key-value pairs will take unique keys with multiple values but not sure how to make use of it.

I'm able to read a file and store in to hash, unsure how to process to the aforementioned format.Any help is really appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always prefer to write programs like this so they read from STDIN as that makes them more flexible.

I'd do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# Read one "chunk" of data at a time
local $/ = '------------------------------';

# A hash to store our results.
my %program;

# While there's data on STDIN...
while (<>) {
  # Remove the end of record marker
  chomp;
  # Skip any empty records
  # (i.e. ones with no printable characters)
  next unless /\S/;

  # Extract the information that we want with a regex
  my ($id, $program) = /ID: (.+?)\n.*Program: (.+?)\n/s;
  # Build a hash of arrays containing our data
  push @{$program{$program}}, $id;
}

# Now we have all the data we need, so let's display it.

# Keys in %program are the program names
foreach my $p (keys %program) {
  say "PROGRAM: $p\n==>ID";
  # $program{$p} is a reference to an array of IDs
  say "\t$_" for @{$program{$p}};
  say '';
}
```

Assuming this is in a program called `programs.pl` and the input data is in `programs.txt`, then you'd run it like this:

```
C:/> programs.pl < programs.txt
```

Comment: Already you did mention the `\n` so what is the use of `s` flag in your pattern?

Comment: Instead of non-greedy use negation character class it also give the same result but steps are less. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xG1uZ3/1)

Comment: It works without `/s` on this data. But I was assuming it wouldn't always be the case that the ID and Program name were on adjacent lines. Probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Always put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in top of the program. And always use three argument for `open`

```
open  my $fh, "<", "D:\\mine\\out.txt";
my %hash;
while (<$fh>){

    if(/ID/)
    {
        my $nxt = <$fh>;    
        s/.*?ID: //g;
        $hash{"$nxt==>ID \n"}.="   $_";
    }


}


print %hash;
```

Output

```
Program: Running
==>ID 
   COM-9090
Program: Swimming
==>ID 
   COM-1234
   COM-2345
   COM-9876
```

I your input file `program` were found at the line after `ID`. So I used
`my $nxt = <$fh>;` Now the program were store into the `$nxt` variable.

Comment: I guess you mean `print Dumper(\%hash)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();
open my $IN, "<", "your file name here" or die "Error: $!\n";
while (<$IN>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/^\s*-*ID:\s*COM/) {
        (my $id) = ($_ =~ m/\s*ID:\s*(.*)/);
        my $prog_name = <$IN>;
        chomp $prog_name;
        $prog_name =~ s/Program/PROGRAM/;
        $hash{$prog_name} = [] unless $hash{$prog_name};
        push @{$hash{$prog_name}}, $id;
    }
}
close $IN;
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Output will be:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'PROGRAM: Running' => [
                              'COM-9090'
                            ],
      'PROGRAM: Swimming' => [
                               'COM-1234',
                               'COM-2345',
                               'COM-9876'
                             ]
    };
```

Let's look at these two lines:

```
$hash{$prog_name} = [] unless $hash{$prog_name};
push @{$hash{$prog_name}}, $id;
```

The first line initiates an empty array reference as the value if the hash is undefined. The second line pushes the ID to the end of that array (regardless of the first line).

Moreover, the first line is not mandatory. Perl knows what you mean if you just write `push @{$hash{$prog_name}}, $id;` and interprets it as if you said "go to the value of this key" and creates it if it wasn't already there. Now you say that the value is an array and you push `$id` to the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked great. Thanks again for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Goku you're welcome.You should read about this feature of Perl called [Autovivification](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=691557).

Comment: Why do the match twice? Surely the first version can become: `if (my ($id) = m/\s*ID:\s*(.*)/) { ... }`.

Comment: `$hash{$prog_name} = () unless $hash{$prog_name};` This is unnecessary (because of autovivification) and wrong (it should be `[]`, not `()`).

Comment: @DaveCross I mentioned that this line is unnecessary, only wanted to be as clear as I can be if he is new to Perl. Same reason for the break of the match to two commands. Of course, you are right about being able to do it in one line. About the brackets, why is it wrong? Worked for me with no errors or warnings.

Comment: `$hash{key} = ()` will create the key but it will have the value `undef`. You say it initiates an empty array, but it doesn't. `$hash{key} = []` creates and anonymous array an sets `$hash{key}` to the reference to that array. Your code works because of the autovivification that takes place on the next line. Your description of your code ("initiates an empty array") is wrong.

Comment: See `perl -MData::Dumper -E'$h{foo} = (); say Dumper \%h` and `perl -MData::Dumper -E'$h{foo} = []; say Dumper \%h'`

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll edit, thanks for the input!